# response.json() is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

Отправляю в компоненте Реакт запрос на сервер фликра, отправляю с axios. Статус запроса 200, но пишет что response.json() не функции.

```
axios.get(url)
  .then(response => 
      {console.log(response.status)
      response.json()})
    .then(data => console.log(data));
    //if (response.status === "200")
   // let photos = response.json();
   // return photos;
```

};

Answer (score 2):

у response и нет функции json. Переданный от сервера ответ будет в response.data
Вот рабочий пример:

```
axios.get(
    url,
    data
).then((response) => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response;
    } else {
        let error = new Error(response.statusText);
        error.response = response;
        throw error
    }
}).then((response) => {
    if (response.headers['content-type'] !== 'application/json') {
        let error = new Error('Некорректный ответ от сервера');
        error.response = response;
        throw error
    }
    return response.data;
}).then((json) => {
    someActionOnSuccess(json);
}).catch((error) => {
     actinOnError(error);
});
```